# nuxt3: use ant-design-vue a-dropdown "document is not defined" error

Tags: antd, nuxt3

nuxt.config.ts

```
// import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
// import { AntDesignVueResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'

// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules:[
    '@ant-design-vue/nuxt'
  ],
  // vite: {
  //   plugins: [
  //     Components({
  //       resolvers: [
  //         AntDesignVueResolver({
  //           importStyle: 'less'
  //         })
  //       ]
  //     })
  //   ],
  //   ssr: {
  //     noExternal: ['ant-design-vue']
  //   }
  // },
  devtools: { enabled: true }
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a-dropdown>
      <a-button>按钮</a-button>
      <template #overlay>
        <a-menu>
          <a-menu-item>1</a-menu-item>
          <a-menu-item>2</a-menu-item>
          <a-menu-item>3</a-menu-item>
          <a-menu-item>4</a-menu-item>
          <a-menu-item>5</a-menu-item>
        </a-menu>
      </template>
    </a-dropdown>
    <!-- <a-button>按钮</a-button> -->
  </div>
</template>
```

After running, the following error is reported

document is not defined

used "unplugin-vue-components" and "@ant-design-vue/nuxt" import mode。 Other components of ant-design-vue can be used normally,all modal box components do not work properly,"document is not defined" error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think some components from ant design vue does not support SSR yet. e.g. the button does work with SSR but the dropdown does not. To fix this, you need to wrap the `ClientOnly` component.

```js
<template>
  <div style="display: flex; gap: 20px;">
    <ClientOnly>
      <a-dropdown>
        <a-button>Dropdown</a-button>
        <template #overlay>
          <a-menu>
            <a-menu-item>1</a-menu-item>
            <a-menu-item>2</a-menu-item>
            <a-menu-item>3</a-menu-item>
            <a-menu-item>4</a-menu-item>
            <a-menu-item>5</a-menu-item>
          </a-menu>
        </template>
      </a-dropdown>
    </ClientOnly>
    <div>
      <!-- This works with SSR -->
      <a-button type="primary">Button</a-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]